# Math symbol in German thesis from 1963

Tags: notation, math-history

I have the following math symbol in a German thesis written in 1963.

[image]

Is it anything more than just a function name?

It is used in the following context

[image]

and then goes on to state that "If the expression is larger than 1, then the cosine must be used instead of "the symbol".

[image]
"Wenn der obige Ausdruck größer als $1$ ist, so muß statt "des Symbols" der cos eingesetzt werden."

The following is my current understanding of the equation given the answers below:

$$
 h_{0} \cong 1.15\sqrt{\frac{|G|}{|F|(\frac{e}{\ell} - 1)(1 - \mathcal{X})}}\frac{d^2}{4\ell} \cosh\left(\frac{\alpha}{3}\right)
$$
with 
$$
 \cosh\alpha = \frac{|W|}{|G|}\sqrt{\frac{|F|}{|G|}}\frac{Hr_{a}}{T_1 + T_2}\frac{\ell}{d^2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{e}{\ell} - 1\right){\left(1 - \mathcal{X}\right)}}
$$

in the case where

$$
\frac{|G|^3}{|F||W|^2}\frac{d^4}{r_a^2l^2}\left(\frac{T_1+T_2}{H} \right)^2 \frac{6\cdot 10^{-5}}{(\frac{e}{l}-1)(1-\mathcal{X})} < 1
$$

when the above equation is greater than 1 then the cosh must be replaced by cos.

Not yet clear where the $6 \cdot 10^{-5}$ is entering from.

Comment: It's "Cos" in "deutsche Schrift". If I remember correctly, some people used $\operatorname{Cos}$ to denote the hyperbolic cosine, $\cosh$, in the old days.

Comment: Might I enquire as to how this became relevant to you?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I am working on book and this equation is in one of the conclusions of a section in a key reference. Want to make sure I am understanding the nuances of the German text correctly.

Comment: @jwpat7 Correction noted.

Comment: it looks like "log" to me

Comment: Curious. If I understand correctly, the cited phrase contained in fact "muß statt [des] Cos der Cosinus eingesetzt werden" (my German is no well enough to know whether "des" would actually be used in this position). The point is that here your symbol is followed two words later by a word that starts identically, _including_ capitalisation. The resemblence in the original handwriting ought to be rather obvious there (except maybe for the third letter, should a non-final "s" get deformed beyond recognition as I suspect from Frunobulax's answer), isn't it?

Comment: @Marc I added a scan of the original text. There had been an edit adding some of the German letters which also changed the capitalization on the cos. However, looking through the other text that is hand written in the thesis my impression is that the writing of cosh in this script was very intentional (ie it is unique and done the same way in these two locations.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image]

Note the "C" (third character in third row) and the "s" (fourth character in second row) above.

The important thing is Daniel Fischer's comment from above that "$\operatorname{Cos}$" here does *not* mean $\cos$ but rather $\cosh$.

Comment: Yes, but "the symbol" $Cos(\alpha)$ does not mean $\cos(\alpha)$, but rather $\cosh(\alpha)$; see the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I didn't say it meant $\cos$.  I posted this after Daniel Fischer's comment above.

Comment: The question was already answered.  I provided context.  What's the problem?

Comment: There are lots of other locations in the thesis with "cos" and "sin" in the equations. This is the only location with the "Cos" symbol.

Comment: It *is* cosinus hyberbolicus, currently it is "cosh" in German. But in older times when the cursive was used, "Cos" with a capital 'C' does indeed mean cosinus hyperbolicus while the "cos" with a small letter means cosinus.

Answer (score 1):

To guess, except x everything else is a constant.

Left hand side of entire last line is proportional to 1/$\sqrt(1- x)$. So,  if

x < 1 the first line is $ cosh( \alpha/3) $ for real argument and, if

x > 1 then first line should be taken to mean $ cos( \alpha/3) $ for imaginary argument

since  $ cosh (i \alpha) = cos ( \alpha) $.

Comment: Here is my current understanding of the equation